# Unable to construct PostgreSQL array literal when text is in Hebrew

Tags: postgresql, internationalization, hebrew

I am writing an Node.js program that is to download arrays of text and save it into a PostgreSQL table with a `text[]` column. When I receive the array, I convert it into an array literal with

```
    /**
     * Convert an array of values into a PostgreSQL array string.
     * @param  {Array}  array JavaScript array
     * @return {String}       PostgreSQL array string
     */
    function arrayToString(array) {
      let values = _.chain(array)
                    .filter(value => value)
                    .map(value => {
                      return '"' + value.replace('\'', '\'\'').trim() + '"';
                    })
                    .join(',')
                    .value();

      return '{' + values + '}';
    }
```

This function converts an array of string `['test1', 'test2']` into an PostgreSQL array literal `{test1, test2}`.

It works well for many languages, but not for Hebrew. Although it can generate an array literal, the result is invalid for PostgreSQL. I am seeing the error like this

```
error: malformed array literal: "{"קק"ל","קקל","יער","ייעור","פורטל השטחים הפתוחים","קרן קיימת לישראל","יערות","צומח","תצורות"}"
```

I also try to manually construct the array in pgAdmin3, but pgAdmin3 has its own problem to deal with Hebrew characters.

How can I insert an array of Hebrew text in PostgreSQL? or I need to break the array and insert each string individually (this works) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't escaping double-quotes in the fields, and your Hebrew text uses the double-quote `U+0022 QUOTATION MARK` in `קק"ל`, which messes up your array literal. If that's meant to be a [gershayim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershayim) it should be the glyph `״` (`U+05f4`), though it could also be `֞`if it's intended as a dicratic mark not punctucation.

That'd make sense given that קק"ל seems to be JNF (Jewish National Fund) according to Google, and that's an acronym, which the gershayim marks. Someone got lazy and typed the wrong glyph, it should be קק״ל. Right?

Unlike normal SQL identifier quoting, Pg array literals use backslash-quoting, so you'd write:

```
{"קק\"ל",קקל,יער,ייעור,"פורטל השטחים הפתוחים","קרן קיימת לישראל",יערות,צומח,תצורות}
```

(If you're using a RTL-capable browser, you'll see the backslash *after* the `"` but it's really before in byte-order).

However, as well as fixing your escaping, I recommend that you switch to using array-constructor form with normal SQL literals:

```
test=> SELECT ARRAY['קק"ל','קקל','יער','ייעור','פורטל השטחים הפתוחים','קרן קיימת לישראל','יערות','צומח','תצורות'];
                                        array                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"קק\"ל",קקל,יער,ייעור,"פורטל השטחים הפתוחים","קרן קיימת לישראל",יערות,צומח,תצורות}
(1 row)
```

I don't speak or read Hebrew, so this is all based on some quick research. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Good catch. I switch to `ARRAY[]` as you suggested and everything works like a charm!

Comment: @HaoliangYu You realise you still need to quote the values, though, right? Otherwise you'll have the same issue if the user input has a `'` in it. Was I right about the punctuation btw?